# show the words in a given string that contain two the same consecutive letters

Tags: c#, forms

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Original string: PHP");
        Console.WriteLine("Test for consecutive similar letters! " + test("PHP"));
        Console.WriteLine("Original string: PHHP");
        Console.WriteLine("Test for consecutive similar letters! " + test("PHHP"));
        Console.WriteLine("Original string: PHPP");
        Console.WriteLine("Test for consecutive similar letters! " + test("PHPP"));
        Console.WriteLine("Original string: PPHP");
        Console.WriteLine("Test for consecutive similar letters! " + test("PPHP"));
    }
    public static bool test(string text)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (text[i] == text[i + 1]) 
                { 
                  return true; 
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

I need to make a C# Sharp program to show the words in a given string that contain two the same consecutive letters in windows forms but i only get it in the console version. Anyone can help me to make this a form application?

Comment: Not sure, what you want to hear... You need a TextBox to enter a string and you need maybe a Button to initiate the test and some Label, to which you can write the result. You could also go without button and react to the Changed Event of the TextBox ... but to give you a complete tutorial, SO is not the right platform for that.

Comment: Maybe just watch some "How-To Winforms" Video on YT, for starters?